# Does $\int _0^1 \cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x^{2}}{x^2+\cfrac{x^3}{x^3+\cdots}}} \, dx$ exist?

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1 \cfrac x {x+\cfrac{x^2}{x^2+\cfrac{x^3}{x^3+\cdots}}} \, dx$$

Does this integral exist?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: omg ur question said hint

Comment: does a solution count as a hint bc same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\int _{0}^{1} \frac{x}{x＋\frac{x^{2}}{x^2＋\frac{x^{3}}{x^{3}＋…}}}dx$

Let's call that monstrous integrand $u$. If you notice, $u=\frac{x}{x+xu}=\frac{1}{1+u}$.

$u+u^2=1$, so $u^2+u-1=0$. This means $u=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \,dx = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}$

Comment: but when $x$ goes to $0$，does $\frac{x}{x＋xu}＝\frac{1}{1+u}$ still hold？

Comment: Short and sweet.

Comment: i guess that's the point of a limit. @Goodboy

Comment: ok，thanks a lot

Comment: No this is wrong, in the recursion $x u = \frac {x^2}{x + \frac{x^2}{x^2 + ...}} \not= \frac {x^2}{x^2 + \frac{x^3}{x^3 + ...}}$